# I want to use graphics in java with event handling

Tags: java, graphics

Problem definition: I want to use graphics in java to print ball and a rectangle ,the ball should move towards the rectangle by arrow keys or mouse moved.

the Problem with the code is that it is printing the ball, again and again, I want to print the ball once only

```
public class MouseGui extends javax.swing.JFrame implements
        MouseMotionListener, MouseListener, KeyListener {

    int x = 10, y = 10;

    public MouseGui() {
        initComponents();
        addKeyListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(final Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(200, 300, 100, 80);
        if (x > 180 || y > 280) {
            g.drawString("Target hit!!", 80, 20);

        }
    }

    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        MouseGui obj = new MouseGui();

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MouseGui().setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(final MouseEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(final KeyEvent e) {
        int a = e.getKeyCode();
        if (e.getKeyCode() == VK_UP) {
            y = y - 10;
            repaint();
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == VK_DOWN) {
            y = y + 10;
            repaint();
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == VK_RIGHT) {
            x = x + 10;
            repaint();
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == VK_LEFT) {
            x = x - 10;
            repaint();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is how this code shows output :

[image]

Comment: Consider indenting your code properly if you would like people to try and read it.

Comment: Use paintComponent instead of  paint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that the ball gets painted multiple times, the problem is that old drawings are never cleared.

When you override paint methods, it is recommended that you call the super method, so that it does its own stuff first .

Calling `super.paint(g)` here , will clear the `Graphics` object :

```
@Override
public void paint(final Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(200, 300, 100, 80);
    if (x > 180 || y > 280) {
        g.drawString("Target hit!!", 80, 20);

    }
}
```

Also, as suggested by @JoopEggen, when doing custom painting on Swing components, you usually use a lower-level component like a `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent` method, i.e :

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(200, 300, 100, 80);
    if (x > 180 || y > 280) {
        g.drawString("Target hit!!", 80, 20);

    }
}
```

See this lesson to get some examples : [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

Calling `super.paintComponent(g)` is a must.

Comment: thnx  a lot VenkyTheCoder

Comment: don't mention it